# how to decodable this JSON with swift 4

Tags: json, swift

I have searched for many tutorial but the problem still exists :(

First see the JSON file :

```
{
   "header":[
      "Academic Year",
      "Scheme Type",
      "Student Type",
      "Institution",
      "Deadline",
      "Remark"
   ],
   "rows":[
      [
         "2018-19",
         "TSFS",
         "Continuing",
         "HKU",
         "17.Apr.18",
         ""
      ],
      [
         "2018-19",
         "TSFS",
         "Continuing",
         "HKBU",
         "23.Apr.18",
         ""
      ]
   ]
}
```

code:

```
import UIKit

struct Header:Decodable{
    let header:[String]
    let row:[Row] 
}
struct Row:Codable{
    let row:[String]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let url =  URL(string: "https://api.data.gov.hk/v1/filter?q=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wfsfaa.gov.hk%2Fsfo%2Fpsi%2Fdeadline%2FSFO_Post_Secondary_Schemes_Application_Submission_Deadlines_en.xlsx%22%2C%22section%22%3A1%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D")
            else {return}

        //get data
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){
            data,response,error in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do{
                let list = try JSONDecoder().decode(Header.self, from: data)
                print(list)
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

error：

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "row", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"row\", intValue: nil) (\"row\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

If I delete “let row:[Row]”  I can get the header part of the data：

```
Header(header: ["Academic Year", "Scheme Type", "Student Type", "Institution", "Deadline", "Remark"])
```

I think it should be a matter of reading the “rows” line, but I can't find a similar solution,
if someone knows how to solve it, please reply me, thank you very much!!

Comment: Hint: "row" and "rows" are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `Header struct` `row` needed to be renamed to `rows` and the `Row struct` is no longer needed.

```
struct Header:Decodable{
    let header:[String]
    let rows: [[String]] 
}
```

Comment: Make it clear that `row` needed to be renamed to `rows` and the `Row` struct is no longer needed.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you. I have edit as per your suggestion